# VSCode notebook silently failing show(modify_doc)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

When using the built-in Jupyter notebook editor in Visual Studio Code and using the `show(modify_doc)` way of plotting, the result is not displayed. Showing individual plots does work.

I tried Googling and reading through the documentation but I couldn't find a solution anywhere. Hopefully someone knows what is wrong here.

(Example taken from the Internet)

Importing necessary modules:

```
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import row, gridplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, curdoc
from bokeh.document import Document
output_notebook()
import numpy as np
```

This does not work as intended in VSCode but it does in the official Jupyter Notebook. I added a print statement as a test and it also does not get printed in VSCode.

```
def modify_doc(doc):
    print("Test")
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)
    TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select"

    p1 = figure(title="Legend Example", tools=TOOLS)
    p1.circle(x,   y, legend="sin(x)")
    p1.circle(x, 2*y, legend="2*sin(x)", color="orange")
    p1.circle(x, 3*y, legend="3*sin(x)", color="green")


    # Add everything to the layout
    layout = row(p1)


    # Add the layout to curdoc
    doc.add_root(layout)

show(modify_doc)
```

The following code *does* run:

```
x2 = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y2 = np.sin(x2)
TOOLS2 = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select"

p2 = figure(title="Legend Example", tools=TOOLS2)
p2.circle(x2,   y2, legend="sin(x)")
p2.circle(x2, 2*y2, legend="2*sin(x)", color="orange")
p2.circle(x2, 3*y2, legend="3*sin(x)", color="green")

show(p2)
```

[image: Showing both code snippets running in VSCode]

Comment: Hey @Laurens. I'm a developer on this extension. I'm not sure if this is a scenario that we have specifically tested before. I'd recommend that you file an issue on our github page here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues
And we can look into it. That's where we do all our work tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me it used to work to output the bokeh figure in a jupyter notebook cell with `show()` in VS Code. But suddenly it stopped working even though I didn't make changes to the code (or reverted the changes to be more precise).

I could resolve the issue by changing the Anaconda environment to another environment and then switching back to the proper environment (see screenshot below).

[image]